# azure mysql [preview] firewall access from Azure App

Tags: mysql, azure, firewall

I am busy testing MYSQL ( preview ) on Azure -  Multiple IIS web apps on Azure App Services need to pull data from Azure MySQL databases.

When setting up Azure MySQL, one of the options is to restrict access to the database by supplying IP addresses that can access it. ( Connection Security in Azure Portal)  Great if you are coming from a VM - but what does one use when one is accessing from Azure Apps ( which use multiple IP's in the 23.102.x.x range. I can obviously open up 23.102.0.1 to 23.102.255.255 but that seems kind of pointless - and dangerous in the long run if MS changes IP's
Any ideas how I can restrict access from my apps/services only ? The public IP of the Apps does not work.

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/concepts-firewall-rules#connecting-from-azure.

Comment: All you have to do is allow access to Azure services for the server's Firewall settings

Answer (score 0):

For Azure MySql go to Connection security and in Access settings select Allow access to Azure services:
[image]